# IOS - How to clean database with NSBatchDeleteRequest

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

With swift 2.1 and CoreData, I want to delete all data of my database.

with following way, it works well

```
let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UserCourse")
let arr = try! context.executeFetchRequest(request)
for item in arr{
    context.deleteObject(item as! NSManagedObject)
    try! context.save()
}
```

but i heard that there is a better way to do that with 
**NSBatchDeleteRequest**

here is the code

```
let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
let model = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectModel
let delete = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Data"))
let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)
try! coordinator.executeRequest(delete, withContext: context)
```

but it raise an error said

```
2015-12-10 01:36:21.195 test[1090:40088] CoreData: error: Illegal attempt to save to a file that was never opened. "This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown).  It cannot perform a save operation.". No last error recorded.
2015-12-10 01:36:21.202 test[1090:40088] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown).  It cannot perform a save operation.'
```

I wonder there must be something wrong with the **model** or **coordinator**, but I can't figure out how to get a correct **coordinator** instance, someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)
```

creates a new `persistentStoreCoordinator`, associated with your model, but does not link it to a `persistentStore`.  Hence the error message.

I suspect actually need to use the existing `persistentStoreCoordinator` associated with your context:

```
let coordinator = context.persistentStoreCoordinator
```